# Replace "var url" using textbox input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So it's my second day with JavaScript and this is what I have done so far:

http://jsbin.com/asale/52/edit?html,output

It shows if a website is online using an image (var url)

I used the YouTube logo in this and as you can see it says online and if you change to link (remove a letter for example) the background changes and it says offline.

My problem is that the textbox does not work, I want to change the "var url" image link (logo for example) by typing it in the box. (I paste the facebook logo image link in the textbox, click Go! and it should say it's online)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'shows if a website is online'. What does that mean? Anyways, by what I can understand, you are looking for the `keyup` event.

Comment: Could you post your code, also?

Comment: How are you checking `if a website is online` ? Do you mean if pinging the server and getting a response ?

Comment: Please note that `<center>` is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple starting point could be giving add an id to the button:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Go!">
```

and then editing a little bit the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showImage(url)
    {
        var url = url || "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif";
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;

        img.onload = function()
        {
            document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/Kkku0Q9.png)';
        }

        img.onerror = function()
        {
            document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/AP8hxNL.png)';
        };
    }

    showImage();

    sub = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    sub.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        // var url = document.getElementsByName('test')[1].value; as one of many alternatives
        var url = e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.value;
        showImage(url);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to change the value of "url" to what is at the textbox.

Modify the html to:

```
<center>
  <form name="test">
    <H2>Check website:</H2>
    <p>
      <input type ="text" name="test" id="txtInput"><BR>
      <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="changeImg()">
    </p>
  </form>
</center>
```

And at the script have

```
function changeImg(){
var url = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
var img = new Image();
img.scr = url;

img.onload = function()
{
// If the server is up, do this. 
document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/Kkku0Q9.png)';
}

img.onerror = function()
{
// If the server is down, do that.
document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/AP8hxNL.png)';
}

}
```

I think you should be good to go!

Comment: It didn't work, nothing happens when clicking the button.

Here: http://jsbin.com/asale/65/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned in jsbin only work on page load. You need to add additional function for reading the text box value and display it in the image. Probably that section is missing in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i got the code to work thanks to ilpaijin.

Also could you tell me how to make it read the box value and display it in the image?

Answer (score 0):

check this...

```
<center>
  <form name="test">
    <H2>Check website:</H2>
    <p>
      <input type ="text" name="test" id="url_field"><BR>
      <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="openURL(document.getElementById('url_field').value);">
    </p>
  </form>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif";

openURL();

function openURL(image)
  {
    if(image!=undefined)
      url = image;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    img.onload = function()
    {
    // If the server is up, do this. 
    document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/Kkku0Q9.png)';
    }

    img.onerror = function()
    {
    // If the server is down, do that.
    document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/AP8hxNL.png)';
    }
  }
</script>
```